# why does iOS app crash when receiving UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c

recently ,i have got a lot of crash logs from customers which using iOS 8.x . here the log,

```
Application received signal SIGSEGV
current state:Foreground,total time:0H0M34S,active time:0H0M29S
iOS Version:8.1.1 (12B435)
(null)
((
0 CoreFoundation 0x219b060f exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) + 151
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x35b53c77 objc_exception_throw + 38
2 CoreFoundation 0x219b053d -[NSException initWithCoder:] (in CoreFoundation) + 1
3 my app 0x47f61b UmengSignalHandler (in my app) + 137
4 libsystem_platform.dylib 0x3622f09b _sigtramp + 34
5 CoreFoundation 0x21968f15 CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation) + 13
6 CoreFoundation 0x281f4e4d _CFXNotificationPost + 1800
7 Foundation 0x225f8ec1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation) + 77
8 Foundation 0x225fda3f -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] (in Foundation) + 31
9 UIKit 0x250bf913 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] (in UIKit) + 139
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x2f78340f _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib) + 23
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x2f798709 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call (in libdispatch.dylib) + 621
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x2f791f3d _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp (in libdispatch.dylib) + 213
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x2f78e035 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp (in libdispatch.dylib) + 329
14 CoreFoundation 0x21976631 CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE (in CoreFoundation) + 9
15 CoreFoundation 0x21974d51 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1513
16 CoreFoundation 0x281f2b31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
17 CoreFoundation 0x281f2943 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
18 GraphicsServices 0x2f5d2051 GSEventRunModal + 136
19 UIKit 0x2b7e86f1 UIApplicationMain + 1440
20 my app 0x28b8cd main (in eif-ios-app) (main.m:27)
21 libdyld.dylib 0x2f7beaaf start (in libdyld.dylib) + 3
)
```

From the log, we can find that app crashed when receiving the low memory warning. my project code never run, So i guess that zombie object happened. 
because zombie is associated with the UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, i searched every place that observing the notification. 
As a result, all the observers removed in dealloc, except one that belong to a singleton. 
now I don't know how to fix this crash. thanks for any help.

Comment: receiving the crash log once again, but this time I find that App stop running at selector setArchiveData in class UINibStorage.  UINibStorage, it  is private class, the UINibStorage object is created and kept by UINib.
I find out that UINib is signed on UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, and while receiving the notification it will execute [self.nibStorage setArchiveData], then crashing.  
Now find the crashing location, but how to fix ? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to debug the issue.

1. While debugging you can check the memory in debug navigator in XCode. The memory should increase if you push new screens, and decrease if you pop screens. If if doesn't decrease, this is perhaps a case of memory leaks and you would need to resolve it to prevent the crash. [image]
2. In XCode, there is a way to generate memory graph while debugging. You can use it to find out the instances where memory leak is happening.

[image]

Comment: @Punnet Thanks for your advice. I checked the memory by the Xcode Memory Graph Debugger and instruments. Unfortunately, I have not found leaks.
I am doubt that it not an issue about memory leaks. If controller have not been released, my app will not crash, because the leaked object can still receive the notification of low memory.